# “Insufficient parameters supplied to the command” error when executing SQLite query

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use the value in a Windows Forms text box as an input for a SQLite query. Basically, I load the SQL and try to set up the parameter (in this case, a "key" for the query).

Here’s my current code:

```
try {
    string connectionString = @" Data Source = c:\milap\milap.s3db; Version = 3";
    var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "select VC1ON from table where trim(key)= @KEY";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(cmd.CommandText, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KEY", key.Text);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) {
        ON1.Text = reader["VC1ON"].ToString();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This always gives me:

> SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

I have also tried:

```
SQLiteParameter param = new SQLiteParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@KEY";
param.Value = key.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

as well as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KEY", key.Text);
```

with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You've got two separate commands going on:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select VC1ON from table where trim(key)= @KEY";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(cmd.CommandText, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KEY", key.Text);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

You've assigned the parameter value to `cmd`, but in the meantime you're actually executing `command`.

Change `cmd.Parameters` to `command.Parameters` and that may get you up and running, but you've got to clean up your code. *(You've got duplicate connection instances too, but that can't be valid because they even have the same name...)*

Here's a quick attempt at cleaning up your code, but it's on-the-fly so you may have to adjust it to get it compile. The `using` blocks ensure you dispose of resources.

```
try
{
    string connectionString = @" Data Source = c:\milap\milap.s3db; Version = 3";

    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select VC1ON from table where trim(key)= @KEY";

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KEY", key.Text);
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                ON1.Text = reader["VC1ON"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What was the problem?! what has changed?!